# Question on raising and lowering operators proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

> How can we show that $\hat{a_+}\hat{a_-}\psi_n = n\psi_n$ if we know that $\hat{a_+}\psi_n = \sqrt{n+1}\psi_{n+1}$ and $\hat{a_-}\psi_n=\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}$?

Is it provable with just these concepts or is more needed? I was thinking we can apply $\hat{a_+}$ to $\hat{a_-}\psi_n=\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}$ which would yield: $$\hat{a_+}\hat{a_-}\psi_n= \hat{a_+}(\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1})$$ but wouldn't the raising operator yield $\hat{a_+}(\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1}) = \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}\psi_n$. Am I going about this the wrong way, or is it indeed provable this way?

Comment: yes I have fixed it

Comment: Note that $\hat{a_+}\psi_{n-1} = \sqrt{n}\psi_n$. This fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done as follows
$$a_+a_-|n\rangle =a_+\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle =\sqrt{n}\ a_+|n-1\rangle =\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}|n\rangle$$
$$\boxed{a_+a_-|n\rangle =n|n\rangle}$$

---

Note:
$$a_-|n\rangle =\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle $$
$$a_+|n\rangle =\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$$

---

Edit: In term of your notation this would go as follows, You just need to change
$$|n\rangle \rightarrow \psi_n$$ So that

$$a_+a_-\psi_n =a_+\sqrt{n}\psi_{n-1} =\sqrt{n}\ a_+\psi_{n-1} =\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}\psi_n$$
$$\boxed{a_+a_-\psi_n =n\psi_n}$$

Comment: I haven't yet learned this notation

Comment: I haven't done anything new. $$|n\rangle \rightarrow \psi_n$$. I'm adding calculation in term of your notation that might help you :)